# Dynmaic XML imports: how to ensure a node placed in a text block remains correctly identified?

Tags: adobe-indesign, xml

I'm setting up an InDesign workflow that relies on dynamic import (links) of XML files. Say I will have many repeated `<item>` tags, each containing a substructure of text and tags for styling. All this content will flow in a main text frame, but I want to be able to extract some item or other and place it in a specific text container (it will thus be removed from the main flow – this works well).

(In the import options, I select "merge content".)

In this scenario, it may happen that some items are added to the XML file while the InDesign document is being laid out. How can I be certain that an item that has been placed in a separate text container remains properly identified in the updated XML import?

It seems that InDesign relies by default on node count, which means that the content may be shifted. (If I placed the third item in a text container, after updating the XML the container will still hold the third item, even if it is not the same).

Is there a way to do otherwise? Is it possible to tell InDesign to look for id attributes on the `<item>` elements to identify them?

EDIT: it seems that InDesign takes into account the element (tag) name to identify it, so having unique element names could solve the issue (but that comes with some drawbacks).